# Can't get attribute 'Word2VecKeyedVectors' on <module 'gensim.models.keyedvectors' >

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I train and save a gensim word2vec model:

```
W2V_MODEL_FN = r"C:\Users\models\w2v.model"

model = Word2Vec(X, size=150, window=3, min_count=2, workers=10)
model.train(X, total_examples=len(X), epochs=50)
model.save(W2V_MODEL_FN)
```

And then:

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec.load(W2V_MODEL_FN)
```

On one enviroment it works perfectly but in another I get the error:

> {AttributeError}Can't get attribute 'Word2VecKeyedVectors' on  module
>   'gensim.models.keyedvectors' from
>   'C:\Users\Anaconda3_New\envs\ISP_env\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py'>

So I guess it might be a package version issue?

But I couldn't figure what it is.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: solved by upgrading to gensim 3.4

Comment: You can write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @oren_jsp [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686366/cant-get-attribute-word2veckeyedvectors-on-module-gensim-models-keyedvector#comment92300426_52686366) to question.

```
pip3 install --upgrade gensim --user
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My case was a different issue.

My code looked like this:

```py
# main.py
from enum import IntEnum
from gensim.models import Word2Vec


class GensimTrainingAlgo(IntEnum):
    SG = 1
    CBOW = 0


model = Word2Vec(X, size=150, window=3, min_count=2, workers=10, sg=GensimTrainingAlgo.SG)
model.save('/tmp/path')
```

It turns out I was breaking pickle. If you want to be able to save/load a function, it must be pickleable. This means it must be [named and importable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

I fixed it by making sure the enum was defined outside the main.py file.

```py
# utils.py
from enum import IntEnum


class GensimTrainingAlgo(IntEnum):
    SG = 1
    CBOW = 0
```

```py
# main.py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec(X, size=150, window=3, min_count=2, workers=10, sg=GensimTrainingAlgo.SG)
model.save('/tmp/path')
```